# Using .gitignore as an Allowlist

Tags: git, gitignore

I'd like to use git to backup my ~/.config folder, and I would like to just upload specific folders. My goal is to make my ~/.config folder into a Git Repo and adding a `~/.config/.gitignore` that allows me to just do `git add . && git commit`, and just having a hand selected set of folders committed to the Repo.

Now my Problem is, that when I try to make a `.gitignore` that ignores everything and then excludes the selected Directorys from that, git just ignores everything and does not care about the Directories I'm trying to be not ignored.

Here's my `.gitignore`:

```
*
!.gitignore
!Jetbrains/**
!Google/**
!autostart/**
!git/**
!nvim/**
!obsidian/**
!polybar/**
```

Comment: You "unignore" files inside the folders, but the folders themselves are still ignored. Try just `!Jetbrains` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the `.gitignore` rules](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format), unanchored patterns are applied at every level, and an ignored directory will never even be scanned. So:

```
/*/
!/Jetbrains
!/Google
!/autostart
```

and so forth. "Ignore all toplevel directories" followed by "except these", and none of those patterns matches anything else.